# How to generate a new application.secret in Play 2.x

Tags: playframework-2.0

Apparently Play 1.x had a command 'play secret' that would create a new application.secret, but I don't see an equivalent command in Play 2.x.  It is recommended to change the key when moving from development to production, so I need to find a way to make a new key for that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are right. I think this feature is not yet implemented in `2.x` version. I am afraid the only way to do is to create a new project. Each new project will generate a new secret key. And then copy only the newly generated key.

I think this issue was raised for your problem: 
https://github.com/n8han/giter8/issues/42 referenced in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/aMyM_fDglSs

Good luck.

**EDIT 2020-01-23:**

It would appear that they went back to camel-case, so on current versions of Play w/ SBT it should be

```
sbt playGenerateSecret
```

**EDIT 2015-05-11:**

As noted by @myk this is now implemented in the sbt plugin, you need to run:

```
sbt play-generate-secret
```

or

```
sbt play-update-secret
```

**Edit 2015-07-02**

Using activator:

```
activator playGenerateSecret
```

Comment: Can we just invent a secret?

Comment: Can you update this answer? The answer below shows that this has been implemented in the `sbt` plugin.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can do it in Scala console:

```
$ scala

scala> val r = new java.security.SecureRandom
r: java.security.SecureRandom = java.security.SecureRandom@b4ca6f6

scala> (1 to 64).map(_=>(r.nextInt(74)+48).toChar).mkString.replaceAll("\\\\+", "/")
res4: String = cCU`liU?i^R3f:Tk3ekG9a0^hjtwADUi@X2OtjAqKG`vv/>dk@cq_QOnu47WQ<0_
```

Your secret is key now is:

```
cCU`liU?i^R3f:Tk3ekG9a0^hjtwADUi@X2OtjAqKG`vv/>dk@cq_QOnu47WQ<0_
```

Answer (score 5):

run

```
sbt play-generate-secret
```

or

```
sbt play-update-secret
```

if you want to update an existing secret in application.conf

More info here 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.2/ApplicationSecret

Answer (score 3):

in play 2.4 use

```
activator playGenerateSecret
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by adis, you can just create a random string and it doesn't even matter if it's longer. Use uuidgen twice to get better entropy than by typing it:

```
application.secret="44786442-c4a6-49b7-a8cc-c44c09c5471d-6b55adcc-efeb-4f6b-b997-b222f3877119"
```

works here without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.6 requires

```
sbt playGenerateSecret
```

command